# How to set RGB color for UILabel in Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I know this can be done programmatically. But I wonder if there's a way to do this in Interface Builder, where I can see how the color looks without launching the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xcode with your UILabel selected, go to the properties panel. Double click on the color property, when the color selector window pops up, select the second tab (sliders).

There is a drop down box that you can select what type of slider you want RGB Slider is one of the options. When you select your color, simply drag it into the color property box.